# Gets working in Main, but not in any other function

Tags: c, gets

Why is gets not taking an input? The code gets compiled but `gets` is skipped. Please help me I am a beginner in c.

When I use the `gets` function in main, it works perfectly.

But when I use it in `add()`, it does not work. What can be the reason behind it.

```
void add()
{
    int a,y,found;
    printf("enter roll number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    y=0;
    while(y<=numberOfRecords)
    {
        if(a==s[numberOfRecords].rollNumber)
        {
            found=1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            found=0;
        }
        y++;
    }

    if(found==1)
    {
        printf("this roll number have been assigned to %c",s[numberOfRecords].name);
    }
    else
    {
        s[numberOfRecords].rollNumber=a;
        printf("enter name of student\n");
        gets(s[numberOfRecords].name);
        printf("student added\n");
        numberOfRecords++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it does not work"?  What exactly is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: Whenever `found == 1` your code will never reach the `gets()` call.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess `main` doesn't call `scanf` before it successfully uses `gets`.

Comment: And I think that you are pressing the return key after the roll number.

Comment: You also have an error in printing the name when found==1.

Comment: Where's you're `main()` that does work?

Comment: Two comments. It smells as though you are having trouble with 0-based array indexing with `while(y<=numberOfRecords)` and later you overwrite the last record when not found. Secondly, shouldn't `if(a==s[numberOfRecords].rollNumber)` be `if(a==s[y].rollNumber)`? Similar error later after `if (found)`

Comment: `gets` has been removed from the latest C standard since it is _impossible to use this function securely_. Of course this does not answer your question, but overall you are on the wrong path with `gets`.

Comment: What is the declaration of s ? Program that run in a context and not in other context is typically of a allocation problem. I think that gets(s[numberOfRecords].name); fill a unallocated zone.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`.  It *will* introduce a point of failure into your program.  It was deprecated in C99 and has been removed from the C2011 version of the language.  Use `fgets` instead.

As to the actual problem, it stems from mixing `scanf` and `gets` in the same code.  When you enter a roll number like `5`, your input stream contains the character sequence `{'5', '\n'}`.  The `scanf` function consumes the `5`, but leaves the newline character in the input stream.

Then, when you enter a name like `"joe"`, the input stream contains the character sequence `{'\n', 'j', 'o', 'e', '\n'}`.  When `gets` reads the stream, the very first character it sees is the newline character left over from the number of rolls input, causing it to return immediately and not read any more text.

There are two ways around this problem.  You can either add a `getchar` call after the `scanf` call (ugly), or use `scanf` with the `%s` conversion specifier instead of the `gets` call, which will skip over any leading whitespace:

```
printf("enter name of student\n");
scanf("%s", s[numberOfRecords].name);
```

However, to be safe, you should use an explicit size on the `%s` conversion specifier to prevent `scanf` from reading more characters than the `name` is sized to hold.  So, if `name` can hold 80 characters, use

```
scanf( "%79s", s[numberOfRecords].name ); // leave 1 for the 0 terminator
```

Comment: Your description of what happens is not entirely correct. _"Then, when you enter a name like "joe"_ doesn't happen. The input buffer still contains the `\n` from the previous input, which will be consumed by the `gets` without giving the user the opportunity to enter anything.